# How to make Visual Studio 2010 + 2012 + 2013 coexist together?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

On my current machine , I need to have Visual Studio 2010 , 2012 & 2013 . Together .

How can I make them coexist together , without one of them causing problems to the other ? Like one big happy family ...

Much appreciated

Comment: I have VS2008, VS2012 and VS2013 with no problems - as long as you install them in the right order (earliest first), it should be fine. What problems are you having?

Comment: @RogerRowland: I had 2013 , and I installed 2010 . After the setup was done , I tried to run the 2010 version but it didn't work .

Comment: I have all three on three machines, never noticed a problem but I don't use the old versions.

Comment: Yes, you need to install VS2010 *then* VS2012, and *finally* VS2013.

Comment: I'm using all versions almost every day and never had any problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to anything special, they can coexist together without any problems. Just install them into separate folders. You should also install them starting with the earliest version (though I installed VS 2013 before VS 2012 and it was fine too).

More information is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx). It contains the following (about Visual Studio 2013):

> You can install this version of Visual Studio on a computer that already has an earlier version installed.

Comment: I also have VS 2008 installed on the same machine and that works fine too.